# Setting Up network in Packet Tracer

Tags: networking, packet, subnet

I am trying to set up a network of 3 router. But when I am trying to send packet from One PC to another it errors on me

```
PC0 ip-address -> 192.1.6.1/24 Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0 Gateway 192.1.6.254
PC2 ip-address -> 192.1.6.2/24 Subnet Mast 255.255.255.0 Gateway 192.1.6.254

Router 5 ip-address-> 192.1.6.254/24
         ip-address-> 192.1.7.254/24

Router 1 ip-address-> 192.1.7.1/24
         ip-address-> 192.1.8.1/24

Router 2 ip-address-> 192.1.8.254/24
         ip-address-> 192.1.9.254/24

PC2 ip-address -> 192.1.9.1/24 Subnet Mast 255.255.255.0 Gateway 192.1.9.254
```

Comment: Do you have any form of routing configured? Configure RIPv2 and it will work or add static routes.

Answer (score 0):

You must set up a protocol like RIPV2 , OSPF , Static Route , so that the router can send the packets